# Is there a way to extract EPS from past years? Additionally, can I do this for P/E ratios (monthly or yearly)? My net goal is to get a 5 year average

Tags: python, web-scraping, yfinance

There doesn't seem to be a specific function (or parameter) that quite fits what I want to do. My net goal is to pull historical EPS and P/E ratios via yfinance for a stock. There seems only a way to do this for the current year.

```
import yfinance as yf
 
ticker = yf.Ticker("TSLA")

current_PE = ticker.info['trailingPE']
print(current_PE)
```

This is the very basic code for current PE ratio.

If anyone has a solution to get historical EPS & PE through yfinance this is optimal!
But of course, any alternatives are also great, scraping Im assuming is viable.

I've also considered trying to manually calculate PE ratios (stock price over EPS), but again, I run into the same issue where I just cannot extract specific historical data